# Correct way of describing a certain trend

Tags: grammar, participles

Is this a correct and natural way of describing this trend?

> **Having increased until about March**, the figure dropped to 0 by June.
> I highlighted the part that confuses me.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I think the verb form is better as *Having **been increasing** until about March...* Perhaps better: ***After** increasing** until about March...* But all forms are perfectly valid, so it's a bit of an Off Topic "beauty context" (matter of opinion).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Having been increasing?? Just: Increasing until about March,

Comment: Graphs are quite often described using the present tenses, even when they show historical data.  *Increasing until mid March, the ____ plummets in April, and by May is approaching zero.*   (The tick marks and label relationshps are unclear, so pay no attention to the months if I have them wrong.)

Comment: @TimR: I think starting an utterance with the "bare" continuous participle like that is a bit "literary". But there's no accounting for taste.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Present tense is used all the time on news programs in the US when charts and graphs are being explained by "the numbers guy", even when the data are showing historical trends. E.g. "We see here the number of registered voters gradually increasing throughout the 1990s". Nobody on TV news here would ever say  **having been increasing** as that is much too much of a mouthful.

Comment: @TimR: Well, I did say *Perhaps better: **After increasing** until about March...* Also, I doubt many querents here really want to learn how to speak English like a newsreader or newspaper headline writer. I'm fine with starting the utterance with ***After...*** like that, but I really do think starting with the continuous form of the *main* verb (as opposed to mine or OP's original auxiliary ***Having** increased / been increasing...*) is a "marked, literary" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Take a gander at *The Economist* and I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples of the present tense being used to describe historical trends.

Comment: Again, do learners want to sound like they write for such august publications as *The Economist*? But let's just leave it at that. We obviously have different ideas about "natural registers".

Comment: Yes, obviously, when you regard **Having been increasing** as more *informal* than  "Increasing..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognise that there are *three*, not just two, notable things on the graph:

- That the data was trending upwards until *April* (I know you said March but the data points seem to be the space *between* the lines on the axis)
- That the data began quickly trending downwards from April.
- That this metric had reached 0 by June.

You only mention the increase and the drop to zero, which is not accurate as the fall took two months (it fell in May, and then again in June).

A concise way to express that might be:

> Initially increasing steadily, the figure sharply declined from April, reaching zero by June.

What I would add is that most 'trends' are usually measured over a much longer period than just 6 months. Depending on what you are measuring and when the data began, this may be better described as "performance" over the period.

Comment: is it correct now?

Comment: @AES Don't edit your question until it's correct, otherwise there will be no question! I see you've added a second version, no - I don't agree with either of them. Speaking as someone working in business intelligence, its very important that you explain the sequence of events. It rose, **then** it fell sharply, **then** it flatlined at 0. You're omitting that change in direction *and* you're using the wrong tense to describe the changes. Look at my example - it isn't the only way to say it, but I believe it is accurate and succinct.

Comment: Using past perfect is wrong?